# Least possible m for which $f(x)=2x^2+3x-m\log x$ is monotonically decreasing on $(0,1)$

Tags: calculus

If the function defined by $f(x)=2x^2+3x-m\log x$ is a monotonically  decreasing function on the open interval $(0,1)$ ,then least possible value of $m$ is:

My attempt:
$$f'(x)\lt0$$
$$4x+3-\frac mx<0$$
$$4x^2+3x-m\lt 0$$
So,
$$9+16m\lt0$$

But I'm stuck after this

The answer is given as $7$ but I'm not sure if its right

Comment: Whence does this $9+16m$ come?

Comment: @zwim The quadratic's discriminant...But that is incorrect.

Comment: @DonAntonio   Isn't it $b^2-4ac=9-((4)(4)(-m))$ ?

Comment: @PiGamma Yes, of course, and that equals $\;9+16m\;$ What I meant is that the use of discriminant here as you did is wrong since we're not interesed in the case where the parabola has no roots...as the accepted answer shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$4x^2+3x-m\lt 0$$

So you need (solving for $m$):
$$m>4x^2+3x$$
But this only needs to hold for $x \in (0,1)$, so...?

Comment: Its open interval right

Comment: I copied that from your question, where it was (indeed) an open interval.

Comment: So how can we substitute $1$?

Comment: Well $4x^2+3x$ doesn't have a maximum on $(0,1)$ since it's monotonically increasing; but if you need $m>4x^2+3x$, you want its supremum (which is of course its maximum on $[0,1]$), so it is easily found by substitution of $x=1$.

Comment: ok..got it now..thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After the last step, you have, for $x\in(0,1)$:

$$m>4x^2+3x$$

Note that on the RHS we have a quadratic expression which is monotonically increasing in $(0,1)$ (Can you tell why?)

Due to this, observe that for the inequality ($m>4x^2+3x$) to hold for all $x\in(0,1)$, $m$ must be greater than the maximum value of $4x^2+3x$ in that interval.

Can you now see where that $7$ came from?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there (don't give up).

$f'(x) \lt 0$ for  $x\in (0,1)$.

$\iff $

$4x^2  + 3x - m \lt 0$ for $x \in (0,1).$

$4x^2 + 3x \lt m; $

Left hand side:

$0 \lt 4x^2 +3x \lt 7$

for $x$ in the interval $(0,1).$

The least possible $m$ is ?